# Gitlab ci rules - use external variables

Tags: syntax, gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, pipeline

I am trying to set a gitlab ci rules in the .gitlab-ci.yaml file,
the purpose is to check if the current branch (that's been merged), is the current release) if it does, enter the script... pretty simple condition.
It does not work, And my guess is that the script block runs after the rules block so the parameter passed in the rules block is not initialized yet.

- **the `ALLOWED_BRANCHES` should be a dynamic parameters comes from a file in the code source.**

which goes like this :

```yaml
onMasterReleaseReleased:
  stage: on-master-release-released
  script:
    - GIT_REMOTE=$(git remote)
    - ALLOWED_BRANCHES=$(git show $GIT_REMOTE/master:version.descriptor)
    - chmod +x ci-bash/roll-up-master-release.sh
    - if [[ $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ $ALLOWED_BRANCHES ]]; then ./ci-bash/roll-up-master- 
         release.sh; else echo "Release did not finished yet."; fi
    - COMMIT_MESSAGE=$(echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE | tr -d "'")
  rules:
    - if: "($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push' && $COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /into/ && $COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /$ALLOWED_BRANCHES/)"
```

any thoughts ?

Thanks !

Comment: you have likely designed it in the wrong order: `ALLOWED_BRANCHES` is set within the script, but already put into `rules: if:` of it. while this still may work or not, this is likely not what you intended.

Comment: also set in the variables block which did not work also.